# How to configure the Length of Primary Key Names using Liquibase Hibernate plugin

Tags: java, hibernate, liquibase

I'm using the Liquibase Hibernate plugin to generate the diffChangeLog from my entity class to my database.

One issue I'm encountering is that the name that Liquibase is generating for Primary Keys is too short.

For example, I have 2 tables,

unsub_template
and 
unsub_template_item

The generated changesets are respectively

```
<changeSet author="rince(generated)" id="1405359138759-50">
        <createTable tableName="unsub_template">
            <column autoIncrement="true" name="id" type="BIGINT">
                <constraints primaryKey="true" primaryKeyName="unsub_templatPK"/>
            </column>
```

and

```
<changeSet author="rince(generated)" id="1405359138759-51">
        <createTable tableName="unsub_template_item">
            <column autoIncrement="true" name="id" type="BIGINT">
                <constraints primaryKey="true" primaryKeyName="unsub_templatPK"/>
            </column>
```

Notice the primaryKeyName attributes are both, unsub_templatPK, 15 characters long

I did some debugging and found the cause for the length to be in `org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass`. A static field, `PK_ALIAS` is defined there

```
private static final Alias PK_ALIAS = new Alias(15, "PK");
```

Is there any way to configure PK_ALIAS?